# Google Cloud SQL import database programatically (without prompt)

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-sdk

I want to export a database and import the output into another database **programatically**. This is what I have so far:

```
gcloud sql export sql instance_name gs://bucketname/db.gz --database=db_name
gcloud sql databases create new_db --instance=instance_name
gcloud sql import sql instance_name gs://bucketname/db.gz --database=new_db

Created database [new_db].                                                                            
instance: instance_name                                                                                                     
Data from [gs://bucketname/db.gz]                                                        
will be imported to [instance_name].                                                                                             

Do you want to continue (Y/n)
```

As you can see the prompt is the issue. 
How can I import it without being prompted? Is there another way to import an export?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **--quiet, -q** parameter when running your `gcloud` command as shown below:

```
gcloud sql import sql instance_name gs://bucketname/db.gz --database=new_db -q
```

The [gcloud Reference](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/) official documentation contains the following explanation about this parameter in case you want to take a look on it:

> --quiet, -q
>
> Disable all interactive prompts when running gcloud commands. If input
>           is required, defaults will be used, or an error will be raised.
>           Overrides the default core/disable_prompts property value for this
>           command invocation. Must be used at the beginning of commands. This is
>           equivalent to setting the environment variable
>           CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS to 1.

Additionally, you can perform the [import](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing#importing_a_sql_dump_file)/[export](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting#mysqldump) tasks by using `cURL` API calls as an alternative option; In this way, you just need to send the [authorized](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/#auth) requests to the service.

*Importing:

```
ACCESS_TOKEN="$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)"
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
 --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 --data '{"importContext":
            {"fileType": "SQL",
             "uri": "gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[PATH_TO_DUMP_FILE]",
             "database": "[DATABASE_NAME]" }}' \
-X POST \
https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/[PROJECT-ID]/instances/[INSTANCE_NAME]/import
```

*Exporting:

```
ACCESS_TOKEN="$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" curl --header "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
     --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     --data '{"exportContext":
                {"fileType": "SQL",
                 "uri": "gs://<BUCKET_NAME>/<PATH_TO_DUMP_FILE>",
                 "databases": ["<DATABASE_NAME1>", "<DATABASE_NAME2>"] }}' \    
-X POST \    
https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/[PROJECT-ID]/instances/[INSTANCE_NAME]/export
```